# How to set the texttype for custom textview in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, textview

How to give the style for the custom textview as password in xcode ios4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
UITextField *textFieldPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 90, 150, 30)];
textFieldPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; 
textFieldPassword.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
textFieldPassword.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
[textFieldPassword setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Comment: can u see my code once   
    textFieldPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 90, 150, 30)];
    textFieldPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textFieldPassword.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textFieldPassword.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

Comment: Hi Rani, here you are using a UITextField not UITextView as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your UITextField is password than just do this

```
[password setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Hope it help you.